# Выделить код в сообщении комита

Tags: python, git, git-commit

Как правильно выделять код в сообщении комита?

Например, комит имеет следующее описание: `add option --help to the hello_world function`. Как в нём выделить `--help` и `hello_world`? Или Git такое не позволяет?

Comment: Не позволяет. Сообщение коммита - простой текст без какого-либо форматирования.

Comment: @zed печально, а есть какие-нибудь сторонние программы/плагины, чтобы можно было бы выделять?

Comment: Мне о таких не известно. И вот [тут](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/6509#issuecomment-486562777) хорошо описано, почему это плохая идея делать поддержку форматирования в отдельно-взятом клиенте, до тех пор, пока это не является частью стандарта.

Comment: `git --no-pager log | какая-нибудь.крутая.программа.для.подсветки.синтаксиса` или переменной `$PAGER` её указать, или конф. опцией `core.pager`. см. `$ man git`